# reusable sub process in JBPM 6.1

Tags: jboss, workflow, jbpm, kie

I want to create a reusable sub processes in jbpm 6, but I cant't see any processes in Called Element pop up. It doesn't load any process information. Please can anyone give me the reason for this situation?

Comment: How are you doing it? Theoretically you only need to create a process and instance it via Call Activity. http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e2961

Comment: After adding a reusable sub process, it gives an error "No callable element specified". Then I was trying to add a process by going properties tab and opening Called Element pop up window, but there was not any processes loaded.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine with Jbpm 5.4. It get all processes from any package. But in jbpm 6.1, it doesn't get newly created processes. In console, there is a log as "Unable to find existing dictionary information". What is the reason for this?

Comment: I too seem to have the same problem

Comment: i followed the steps of @Grady G Cooper. but when i execute the parent process, gives me error saying that "[com.ZZ.parent:1 - Call Child process:2] -- Could not find process com.ZZ.childProcess". my child process id is mentioned correctly in call activity of parent process. do i have to add any file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question/issue. However, I have successfully used reusable suprosses in JBPM 6.1.0.Final and eclipse.
These are steps:

1. Create a resuable subprocess with and ID.  Make note the ID for steps 2-5.

[image]

2. Drag and Drop a "Call Activity" Activity to the bpmn
3. Edit the properties of the "Call Activity" - click on "Call Activity" and go to eclipse properties tab.

[image]

5. Click on "pencil" edit icon:

[image]

5. Enter the reusable subprocess id in edit window and type reusable subprosses id and hit o.k.

You should be able to run you bpmn and see the execution of subprocess.

Comment: How can I get the `processInstanceId` of the called activity? Usually, we can use `startProcess()` to get the `process` and then call the `getProcessInstanceId()` to get the `processInstanceId` but in this case jbpm starts the called activity by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hitted this error today at work, using 6.1.0.Final. **If process id has underscores it will not show in workbench *called activity* popup**. Look at [the sources](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-designer/blob/6.1.x/jbpm-designer-backend/src/main/java/org/jbpm/designer/web/server/CalledElementServlet.java#L100):

```
Asset<String> processContent = ServletUtil.getProcessSourceContent(p, profile);
Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("<\\S*process[^\"]+id=\"([^_\"]+)\"", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher idMatcher = idPattern.matcher(processContent.getAssetContent());
if(idMatcher.find()) {
    String pid = idMatcher.group(1);
    String pidcontent = ServletUtil.getProcessImageContent(processContent.getAssetLocation(), pid, profile);
    if(pid != null && !(packageName.equals(processPackage) && pid.equals(processId))) {
        processInfo.put(pid+"|"+processContent.getAssetLocation(), pidcontent != null ? pidcontent : "");
    }
}
```

That regex used to get process id will not match "_". Check that your process id is valid.